# Multi-Level Off-Canvas Menu with Angular-Foundation

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation, angular-foundation

I am trying to get multi-level off-canvas menus working with angular-foundation. However, whenever clicking the sub menu link, the menu closes completely instead of showing the sub menu.

The code is taken from the foundation example:

```
<aside class="left-off-canvas-menu">
    <ul class="off-canvas-list">
        <li><label>Foundation</label></li>
        <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Submenu</a>
           <ul class="left-submenu">
              <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
              <li>
                <label>Level 1</label>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
              <li class="has-submenu"><a href="#">Link 2 w/ submenu</a>
                <ul class="left-submenu">
                  <li class="back"><a href="#">Back</a></li>
                  <li>
                      <label>Level 2</label>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
</aside>
```

Here is a Plunker showing the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/cHnMY8dSWiAqyezCzIMS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that this feature is just not implemented yet.

https://github.com/pineconellc/angular-foundation/pull/137